# Why does std::filesystem::copy_file() ignore the create_hard_links option flag?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++17, std

I am writing a function to copy large binary images around.  I first try to copy them by hard link.  If that fails, then I fallback to copying them normally.

I initially wrote the function to use `std::filesystem::copy_file()`, like this:

```
public bool CopyLargeStaticFile(const path& source, const path& dest)
{
    // First try a hard-link.

    std::error_code ec;
    copy_file(source, dest, copy_options::create_hard_links, ec);

    if (ec)
    {
        // On error, fall-back to a regular copy.  When copying to a different
        // disk, I would expect this error but it does not happen because copy_file
        // ignores the 'create_hard_links' flag and just makes a regular copy

        ec.clear();
        copy_file(source, dest, ec);
    }

    return !ec;
}
```

But then I discovered that the create_hard_link flag is not honored when you call copy_file. If you want it to be honored, you must instead call filesystem::copy.

Does anyone know why? Is there some technical reason? Is it an oversight of the filesystem spec? Something wrong with the Visual Studio implementation? It just makes no sense to me.

Editing to add: After I discovered this, I did come across the mention in the [`copy_options` enum](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/copy_options) that the flag only applies to `copy()`.  Just don't understand the "why" of it.

Comment: Is this on Windows?  Might not be implemented, nobody seems to use hard links there.  You could try `create_symlinks` instead; I prefer those anyway.

Comment: Actually plenty of people use hard links on Windows.  It's a great way to save disk space while having the file look exactly like a file -- needing no special, symlink handling

Comment: What I'd like to see in the C++ standard would actually be a `create_ref_links` (and `create_ref_links_if_possible`) to use copy-on-write features of modern filesystems (though Windows support for CoW outside of Windows Server is kind of 'eh' at the moment).

Comment: This looks like a design issue, if you have any ideas, you could go to [DC](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=8&entry=problem) and report it.

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the C++ standard for [copy_options](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/copy_options), you'll see that `create_hard_links` is designed to only affect `copy()` and not `copy_file()`. If you look at Microsoft's [implementation](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/994f94199c561a38a4a8e15584030160095bc25a/stl/src/filesystem.cpp#L354) of `copy_file()`, you'll see that it only looks at the bits of `copy_options` that are part of the "what to do with existing files" logic.

So unfortunately for you, Microsoft's STL follows the standard here, and what you're trying to do simply won't work.

Technically you're even skirting around undefined behavior here:

> The behavior is undefined if there is more than one option in any of the copy_options option group present in options (even in the groups not relevant to filesystem::copy_file)

Since you only specify `create_hard_links` you're still technically not invoking UB (and Microsoft's implementation would be lenient here anyway), but it simply won't have any effect.

I don't know for sure, but my guess is that the reasoning here would be that `copy_file` is designed to explicitly copy the contents of a file (and not care about fancy filesystem features), while `copy` is a higher-level routine. (The standard itself says that `copy` may call `copy_file` in some cases.)

Hence, if you want hard links, simply use `copy`.

Comment: Thanks.  Actually I did see the documentation after the fact.   https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/copy_options   Meant to mention that in my post.    I will edit it for clarity.  My question is mostly a philosphical one:  Why share the same options enum for two functions that do very, very similar things and arbitrarily not allow one of them to use a given flag.

Comment: Well, as for why this is exactly the way it is: `std::filesystem` is basically just `boost::filesystem` with some minimal changes. `boost::filesystem` has the same `copy_options` logic. As for the philosophy behind `copy_file` not accepting the other options: as I said above, I believe `copy_file` is intended to copy the file **contents**, and not do any fancy filesystem logic.

Comment: I get your drift but that does not follow;  Boost's `copy_file` did not even have hard links.  The C++ `<filesystem>` functions have grown beyond (or at least with) what they got from Boost.  `std::filesystem::copy` is new to C++17.  the `copy_options` flags and their addition to the `copy_file` function are also new.    It makes no sense to add those options to an overload of `copy_file `and then arbitrarily keep one from working.  The old overloads still work as before;  You won't get a hard-link by accident.  Anyway I hope they eventually apply some uniformity thoughout the API.